# how to convert a multi-inheritance to a single inheritance

Tags: c++, mfc

in my mfc souce code, there are some classes, which are multi-inheritance. Like:

> class CGraphComboBox:public CComboBox, public virtual CGraphBaseClass
>
> class CGraphFrame:public CFrameWnd, public virtual CGraphBaseClass
>
> class CGraphPanel:public CWnd, public virtual CGraphBaseClass

class CGraphBaseClass is like:

```
class CGraphBaseClass
{
    public:

    typedef int(*BaseClassWndCallbackFunc)(CGraphBaseClass* base_class, void* param);

    public:
    CGraphBaseClass(){};

    virtual CGraphWnd* get_main_graph_window();
    virtual void AppendMenuItems(CMenu* menu){};

    void EnumerateParentWindows(BaseClassWndCallbackFunc enum_func, void* user_data);
};
```

One of their base class is MFC standard classes which I cannot modify(eg. CComboBox), another base class(CGraphBaseClass) is my own class.
The reason I make class CGraphBaseClass as virtual, is because in other location, I need to dynamic bind its functions.

like below code:

```
int AppendMenuForAllParents(CGraphBaseClass* base_class, void* param)
{
    CMenu* menu = reinterpret_cast<CMenu*>(param);
    base_class->AppendMenuItems(menu);
    return 0;
}
```

in these classes, eg.CGraphPanel, there are some MESSAGE_MAP. eg:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGraphPanel, CWnd)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CGraphPanel)
    ON_WM_PAINT()//C4407
    ON_WM_CREATE() //C4407
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()//C4407
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

because classes' multi-inheritance and virtual base class, there will be

> warning C4407:cast between different pointer to member representations, compiler may generate incorrect code

in these message map.

meanings

```
#define ON_WM_CREATE() \
    { WM_CREATE, 0, 0, 0, AfxSig_is, \
        (AFX_PMSG) (AFX_PMSGW) \
        (static_cast< int (AFX_MSG_CALL CWnd::*)(LPCREATESTRUCT) > ( &ThisClass :: OnCreate)) },
```

would not generate the correct code.

My question is: how could I refactor the code, to avoid these multi-inheritance?

Comment: Did you ever read about "Composition over inheritance"? I would invest in making the `CGraphBaseClass` part composed instead of inherited.

Comment: If I compose CGraphBaseClass to CGraphPane etc, then these three Classes CGraphPane,CGraphFrame and CGraphComboBox would have no relationship. So I cannot use a run-time bind to execute the code base_class->AppendMenuItems(menu); I guess it would be a bad design

Comment: You basically have an interface. You could have your window classes implement the interfaces/classes internally, and then respond to a message by returning the interface. For instance, a messsage like (WM_APP+1) defined in each window class. Response function returns a pointer to the internal class... Or, declare a COM interface and implement the interfaces since MFC window classes are COM capable.

Comment: I have used similar designs (without virtual inheritance though) without any issue and I don't remember this compiler warning. According to [this technical note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267985(v=vs.60).aspx) it should work if some constraints are respected. Granted, it's for VC 6.0 so this may no longer apply to recent versions of VC. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179534/message-map-mfc-with-multiple-inheritance-how-to-avoid-warning-c4407-and-runtim). [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562534/what-problems-could-warning-c4407-cause)

Comment: I was able to reproduce only by using virtual inheritance. Do you really need virtual inheritance? From your sample code it doesn't appear that you have a diamond problem to solve.

Comment: yes, virtual is needed here, because in other places I will use the CGraphBaseClass pointer to handle different derived class. If no virtual, the result would be different.